# nhibernate mapping enum pair (key - value)

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In our system we are using nhibernate for mapping objects into database. In one of the our objects
we have field, which is represented as enum (enum with key and value, f.e.

```
public enum Status
    {
        Draft = 0,
        Archived = 1,
        Imported = 2
    }
```

)

So, in our application we faced with problem for sorting objects by that field which is represented by enum: sorting is made not by key of enum, but by value. For fixing that problem we created addtive field in database for string key of enum and made changes in nhibenate model file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <typedef name="StatusName" class="NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType`1[[Code.Model.Status, Code.Model]], NHibernate" />
...
<property name="Status"  type="StatusName" column="StatusName" not-null="true" />
...
```

After that changes sorting started working correctly in application (records are sorted by enum key), but after creating new objects in database is saved value only for enum key (StatusName field) and for enum value (Status field) it doesn't save.

Is there any way to map key and value of enum to database columns (Status and StatusName columns) by using nhibernate configurations?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. It think that you want to store both the name of the enum value as well as its number value to the database in two different columns.

Before you do that, be sure that you really want that. It is a redundancy. Redundancies are always tricky to keep consistent and are usually causing more problems as they solve.

To implement it, you need to write a composite [custom type](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-custom), which is able to store the value of a property to multiple columns.

There are several examples in the net, eg. [here](http://www.milkcarton.com/blog/2006/12/31/CompositeUserTypes+In+NHibernate.aspx) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189418/using-nhibernate-icompositeusertype-with-a-value-type).